# Is weak convergence only defined for probability measures on metric spaces with Borel sigma algebra?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, weak-convergence

When searching for a definition of weak convergence for probability measures I find only definitions with them being defined on metric spaces with Borel sigma algebra. Is it really only defined on those spaces?

Can we not define it for general topological spaces with Borel sigma algebra?

Comment: You can find weak convergence for sequences in Banach Banach space as well... and I can imagine that you can find it for many other things...

Comment: The trouble is that weak (actually weak*) limit of probability measures need not be probability measures once you venture away from compact metric spaces, and the further you move away, the less is preserved.  You could try to salvage this situation somewhat (that is why we can define weak convergence on complete metric spaces) but that is usually too much work for not much benefit.

Comment: Measurability of bounded continuous functions is required for the definition to make sense. In many cases this automatically implies that the  given  sigma algebra contains all Borel sets.

Comment: Thanks, I corrected this in the question.

Comment: And why limit yourself to probabilities!? All the "trouble" are actually interesting facts!!!!!! :-)

Comment: @user10354138: I don't know how you can conclude about "not too much benefits". Even if you want to keep compactness, I see no real need for metrizability. For that reason you have the topological concept of "compact Hausdorff", and also the measure theoretic concept of "Radon measures".